# Set string systemvaribale in CANoe from python

Tags: python, capl, canoe

I am trying to set a system varibale in CANoe from python over COM.
I have managed to set a integer system varibale from python like this

When setting the integer system varibale I am  doing this ( which works)

```
    self.Application = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("CANoe.Application")
    Ver = self.Application.Version
    self.Namespaces = self.Application.System.Namespaces
    self.Namespace = self.Namespaces('BOT')

    Machine = self.Namespace.Variables('Machine')
    Machine.value = 8
```

But if the system varibale in CANoe is a string (in CANoe)

```
    Machine = self.Namespace.Variables('Machine')
    Machine.value = getText() // will return "8"
```

My python script just crash

```
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 707, in __setattr__
raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Property '<unknown>.value' can not be set.
```

How can i set the string system varibale from python over COM to CANoe?

Edit;

I solved it.

The Machine.value needs to be set like this

```
Machine = self.Namespace.Variables('Machine')
var = getText() // will return "8"
Machine.value = var
```

For some reason i need to save the value in a variable before setting the system varibale